# A call to a generic function (with constraints implemented with an interface) produces an error about missing constraints. What do I fail to see?

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, math, vs-error

I want to do some arithmetic addition in my generic class with some constraints in place. For brevity, assume there is just one public member named `Value`.

```
Public MustInherit Class GenericInterval(Of T As {Structure, IComparable})
    Public Value As T

    '(1) filled in below
End Class
```

Outside the class, I have an interface and a structure implementing it as follows:

```
Public Interface IAddable(Of U As {Structure, IComparable})
    Function Add(a As U, b As U) As U
End Interface

Public Structure Int64Calculator
    Implements IAddable(Of Int64)

    Public Function Add(ByVal a As Int64, ByVal b As Int64) As Int64 _
        Implements IAddable(Of Int64).Add
        Return a + b
    End Function
End Structure
```

This enables me to create a function in my class at position marked (1) above. There are some constraints, but as far as I can tell, I think I got that part right. `New` on `C` is needed, otherwise `As C = New C()` would not be possible.

```
Public MustInherit Class GenericInterval(Of T As {Structure, IComparable})
    Public Value As T

    '(2) filled in below

    Private Function Add(Of U As {Structure, IComparable},
                            C As {IAddable(Of U), New}) _
                        (ByVal a As U, ByVal b As U) As U

        Dim calc As C = New C()
        Return calc.Add(a, b)
    End Function
End Class
```

Now I intended to use this function to do calculations in the class' overridden `GetHashCode` function, as follows:

```
Public MustInherit Class GenericInterval(Of T As {Structure, IComparable})
    Public Value As T

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Const HASHPRIME_1 As Int64 = 4294967291    '32 bits.
        Dim lCompHash As Int64          'Partial hash for actual component.

        lCompHash = Add(Of T, Int64Calculator)(Value, HASHPRIME_1)
    End Function

    '... as above
End Class
```

However, VS complains with error [BC32044](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/misc/bc32044), the squiggly underlines referring to

```
Add(Of T, Int64Calculator)
```

stating

> "Type argument 'Int64Calculator' does not inherit from or implement
>   the constraint type 'IAddable(Of T As {Structure, IComparable})'".

Only that I think that the structure `Int64Calculator` does implement that constraint indeed via `Implements IAddable(Of Int64)`.

What do I miss?

Comment: `GenericInterval` does not enforce `T` to be `Int64`. So at the point when `Int64Calculator` is tested for validity, it is required to handle any `T as {Structure, IComparable}`, not just `Int64`. You can fix that with `lCompHash = Me.Add(Of Int64, Int64Calculator)(Me.Value, HASHPRIME_1)`, but then you'll have another error about `Me.Value` not necessarily being convertable to `Int64`.

Comment: @GSerg I think this is the answer and that you should post it.

Comment: @Grax I didn't on the basis that it does not explain what to do with the `Me.Value` situation, so it just changes the problem to a different problem.

Comment: @GSerg, I appreciate your explanation, but will still wait 1 or 2 more days for maybe a slightly different working approach, after which I would ask you to turn it into an answer proper, too, as "unsolvable" for sure is a valid answer. Of course, if I was just after the addability without caring for OO and strong typing, and was certain that only number types could be processed (possibly using narrower constraints, if I find any), one could simply do `Dim oValue as Object = Value` followed by `lCompHash = CType(oValue, Int64)` (with floats rounding).

Comment: @Herb Could you explain what you are [ultimately trying to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) and how the intended use of `GenericInterval` would look like?

Comment: @GSerg, I could write several pages about its use (I did already in Word, actually), but here, this is not the point. _I do not need arithmetics in this class. Absolutely not._ But I do need to implement `IComparable` and need also to override `Equals`. Which is done without any arithmetics. So far, so good. However, MS strongly advises to override also `GetHashCode` ((1) reference source, and worse (2) here) when doing so. It is _just here_ that I need maths. There will be more generics with the exact same problem. I thought an interface would be possibly a good idea. Maybe it wasn't.

Comment: (1) [link](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,4de9cf234d0d8b16), 
(2) [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You're probably better off going with `public override int GetHashCode() { return Tuple.Create(x, y).GetHashCode(); } ` where `x` and `y` (and possibly other values) are the values that you use in your equality comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part 1:** 
As @Gserg commented:
`GenericInterval` does not enforce T to be `Int64`. So at the point when `Int64Calculator` is tested for validity, it is required to handle any T as `{Structure, IComparable}`, not just `Int64`. You can fix that with `lCompHash = Me.Add(Of Int64, Int64Calculator)(Me.Value, HASHPRIME_1)`, but then you'll have another error about Me.Value not necessarily being convertable to `Int64`.

**Part 2:**
This simplest way to implement GetHashCode for the case where you consider objects as equal based on certain properties is to use `Tuple.Create(x,y).GetHashCode()`

For example, if you consider properties equal that have the same `Name` and `PhoneNumber` properties, then the following code would return a usable HashCode.

```
public override int GetHashCode() { return Tuple.Create(Name, PhoneNumber).GetHashCode(); }
```